# VS Code shortcut to focus integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

**UPDATE: This issue fixed in a later version of VS Code (tested 1.41.1) control + ` works for both opening and focusing events**

How to focus to the integrated terminal while it is showing?

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

There's a shortcut to show the integrated terminal. But that will hide the terminal if it's already open. It would be nice if there's a shortcut to focus on terminal while typing on editor.

Comment: what's wrong with `command`+`'`?

Comment: This question is old and seems no longer valid for the newer version (I'm testing 1.41.1). VS Code developers have fixed that. Now `command + \`` focuses if the panel is visible.

Comment: Right now it's 'ctrl + `' on MacOS

Comment: The `Ctrl + \`` binding doesn't seem to be default on Windows. See more details in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47912353/1944

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **Terminal: Focus Terminal** command. By default it's not assigned to a shortcut but you can easily do this using the keyboard shortcut preferences.

You can also call it from the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) by pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> and typing `Focus Terminal`.

Keep in mind that this command will also create a new integrated terminal window if one is not already active.

[image]

To access the keyboard shortcuts preferences, activate the Command Palette by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and then type `open keyboard shortcuts`. To assign new shortcut for a command, press the `+` symbol visible on the left side of a row. Popup will appear where you should record your desired keys.

Comment: In addition, it's okay to double up on the `Ctrl`+`\`` command for this. When no terminal is open, it will be opened, and if a terminal is already open, it will simply be focused. I think this is the expected behavior most users expect out of the box.

Comment: As of the latest insiders build, it looks like the Terminal Focus hotkey is now also bound to `Ctrl`+`\``

Answer (score 65):

### Super-simple answer

If the terminal is **not** already displayed, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

If the terminal **is** displayed, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> twice.

*Note:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> *is* <kbd>Command</kbd> *on Mac.*

---

### More complicated answer

Open the **Command Palette** and search for **Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts** for details of current keyboard shortcuts.

[image: Open Keyboard Shortcuts]

Some people (and the [official shortcuts reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)) report that the following work out-of-the-box:

- Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> or
- Win/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

(that's a [backtick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick) or grave, not an apostrophe, single-quote, or prime)

As far as I can see, by default as of `1.72.2` and `1.73.0-insider`, this shortcut is **not** bound by default (on Windows, at least).

[image: Ctrl+` is not bound by default]

This could be because, on Windows, the backtick key on many (most?) PC keyboards is an [OEM key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582502/1944) (in my case, `oem_8`).

---

**If you want to manually add the bindings to toggle between terminal and editor, do this:**

1. Open keyboard shortcuts (**Command Palette** > **Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts**)

   [image: Open Keyboard Shortcuts]
2. Find **Terminal: Focus Terminal**, set your preferred keybinding, and set the **When** value to `!terminalFocus` (right-click > **Change When Expression**)
3. Find **View: Focus Active Editor Group**, set your preferred keybinding (can be same so it acts as a toggle), and set the **When** value to `terminalFocus`.

   [image: keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Answer I was looking for (Cmd+J on a mac).

Comment: With vscode 1.73.1 (or some very recent version close before that), there has been a behaviour change: Ctrl-J works better than Ctrl-\`. In particular, when you first start vscode, Ctrl-\` won't do an initial focus-switch to the terminal like it did in older versions of vscode, and hence an additional press won't hide the panel containing it. Ctrl-\` still works in every other situation. However, Ctrl-J works in all situations, so a double Ctrl-J is useful to hide that panel on startup, so you can see more editor space.

Answer (score 13):

@ringo-de-smet

The `keybindings.json` you shared didn't work for me in @code 1.25.1. I just had to change a little bit:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+y",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
  "when": "editorFocus"
},
{
  "key": "cmd+y",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

Comment: I needed to use the 'oem'-code of the key to make it since it was a special (non-US) character.

Comment: nice, but I use key "cmd/ctrl+`" instead

Answer (score 11):

I have added the following to my `keybindings.json` file:

```
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+`",        
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
    "when": "editorFocus"
},
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+`",        
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
    "when": "explorerViewletFocus"
}
```

This covers for me the majority of cases: when my Explorer has focus or when an editor has focus, the same key binding will focus on an existing terminal without toggling it.

You can find all the available `when` clauses in the [VSCode KeyBindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) documentation.

This doesn't conflict with the same keybinding already in use globally for `workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal`.

Answer (score 8):

I guess the shortcut to show terminal you are using is <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, it will only show/hide terminal panel. If you want to focus on terminal when it is showing, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: No it doesn't work, both cmd+j and ctrl+` toggles the terminal pane

Answer (score 4):

Although the accepted answer is best, there is way to focus in the terminal without modifying settings.

If already visible, typing CTRL + ` twice will first close the terminal console, and then reopen with focus in it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently want to change this hotkey binding too
Here is what I did on my mac:

1 Open Keyboard Shortcut Editor
Use HotKey: cmd + K + cmd + S
OR visual way: Code -> Preferences -> keyboad Shortcuts

2 Search
View: Toggle Integrated Terminal

3 Edit
Change to your favourite bindings