# WPF Add KeyBinding events with umlaut characters in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, key-bindings

Can anyone tell me why keybinding events do not work with umlaut characters like this?

[image]

Trying in xaml

```
<Grid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Ü" ... />
</Grid.InputBindings>
```

Will throw error:

> Cannot convert string value 'Ü' to type `System.Windows.Input.Key`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a small test program to find out which `Key` is what. Make new WPF project and add to main window cs-file:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var skip = new[] { Key.None, Key.DeadCharProcessed };
    foreach (Key value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)))
        if (!skip.Contains(value))
            InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding { Command = new MyCommand(value.ToString()), Key = value });
}

public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public string Text { get; }

    public MyCommand(string text) { Text = text; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => MessageBox.Show(Text);
}
```

To save you time:

```
Ü = Key.Oem1
Ö = Key.Oem3
Ä = Key.OemQuotes
```

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582403/what-are-the-oem-keys-in-the-system-windows-forms-keys-enumeration suggests these may change with keyboard manufacturer, so OP might have to find a different solution...

Comment: @Will, you just saved 2 people from angry customers, thanks. To follow my solution one has to provide mechanism to redefine keys in his software.

Comment: @Sinatr: Thank you so much. Now I understand and can make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Because `KeyBinding.Key` is enumeration, you can see all possible values [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx). Since your umlaut character is not part of that enumeraton - you cannot use it.